# Proving spherical harmonics' spherical symmetry and invariance under rotations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, quantum-spin, spherical-harmonics

I was told in a lecture the following relationship, where $Y_{\ell}^m$ are the spherical harmonics and the eigenfunctions of the two following operators:

$$ L^2  Y_{\ell}^m = \ell(\ell + 1) \hbar^2 Y_{\ell}^m $$

$$L_z Y_{\ell}^m = m \hbar Y_{\ell}^m $$

We were also told that these two operators $L^2$ and $L_z$ show spherical symmetry, and so the spherical harmonics are invariant under rotations.

However if you look into the exact solutions for the spherical harmonics you will see they depend on the angles (θ, φ), so how can spherical symmetry be proven if the eigenfunctions depend on angles and not only the radius?

Moreover how can they be invariant under rotations if any rotation (unless the angle matched the period of the harmonic) changes the angle the spherical harmonic takes as input?

Comment: Hard to believe you heard "invariant under rotations"! You were [taught](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Rotations) how they transform among themselves under rotations, maintaining $\ell$ and scrambling *m*s , unless the rotation is around the *z* axis, in which case the  φ just shifts...

Comment: $L^2$ is invariant under rotations, but I don't think $L_z$ is.  $L_z$ is invariant under rotations about the $z$-axis, though.

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes, you're right about the invariance point. How would you account for the spherical symmetry point?

Comment: They comprise the [spherical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis) suited to a sphere.

Comment: That is, since the spherical harmonics form a complete set of orthogonal functions and thus an orthonormal basis, each function defined on the surface of a sphere can be written as a sum of these spherical harmonics.